# PHP number tag max based on totalquantity input

Tags: php

I am trying to use totalquantity dynamic value as inputquantity input's max value. Please help me to know the correct way in HTML or PHP or Java function.

```
<td style="padding-left:20px;">
    <input type="text" name="totalquantity[]" id="totalquantity<?php echo $x; ?>"  autocomplete="off" disabled="true" class="form-control" />
</td>
                            
<td style="padding-left:20px;">
    <input type="number" name="inputquantity[]" id="inputquantity<?php echo $x; ?>" min="1" max="<?php $_POST['totalquantity']?>" onkeyup="getvalue(<?php echo $x ?>), getTotal(<?php echo $x ?>)" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Maybe you should also show us the javascript

Comment: I am Sorry confusion on my question. I would like to set min max value for my 2nd html input tag(inputquantity) and max value should not greater than my first totalquantity input value

Comment: Change max="<?php $_POST['totalquantity']?>" to max="<?php echo $_POST['totalquantity']?>"

Comment: I added your command.....max="<?php echo $_POST['totalquantity']?>" . but max is not working.

Comment: @RiggsFolly is it possible to call another input value in same form or any chances by function onkeyup?

Comment: This?? `onkeyup="getvalue(<?php echo $x ?>), getTotal(<?php echo $x ?>)"`

Comment: this is being used here for another logics getvalue = inputquantity*rate.. and getvalue = fetching db product.quantity value